# Particular verbal inflection classes in "The Proclamation of Henry III"

Tags: historical-linguistics, english

I'm reading a document about "The Proclamation of Henry III", in which the text is presented and a short commentary and glossary follow.

I'm interested in the survival of some of the distinct verbal inflections classes of Old English. 
In particular, I'm referring to the verbs "swerien", "makien" and "werien": I noticed that these particular verbs ends in *-ien*, while the usual suffix of the infinitive/subjunctive verbal forms in the text is *-en*.

In the glossary, I came across some dictionary-like entries, such as this:

**swerien**, 4, swear, 3 p. pi. subj. after *hoaten* ; ags. *swerian* 
inf., *swerion* subj. ; ge. *sweren*; p. 85. Str. 560.

Can you help me to find out what is special about these verbs?

Comment: There's a suffix -i- (-j-) in ME swerien and ME wearien, which also caused umlaut of the root vowel, cf. Gothic swaran - OE swerian or Gothic wasjan - OE werian.